# Data structure to store intervals and allow fast deleting?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

A friend of mine was asked the following question during interview:
You need to design a data structure that stores intervals with an ID like 1:{1,5}, 2:{2, 10}, 3:{4, 20} ... and given a val x, you should be able to delete intervals that contain x as fast as possible.

For example, if x = 3, both 1:{1,5} and 2:{2,10} should be deleted.

It's easy to do it in linear time, so I guess the interviewer is looking for log(N) solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: If you have to guess what the interviewer meant, the interviewer was doing something wrong.

Comment: @amit   Thanks, I think that's it... I didn't learn interval tree in school though

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 , fast deletion (log(n))

Break down the intervals into smaller, disjoint intervals (Eg  1:{1,5}, 2:{2, 10}, 3:{4, 20} becomes  {1,2} {2,4} {4,5} {5,20};

Build an interference graph with Edge in [NewInterval X OrginalInterval] where  (a,b) means that the new interval a is included in the orginal interval b;

Deletion procedure :
For a given x, find the new interval which included x ( log n, since the new intervals can be sorted)
Marks that new interval as deleted.

To list the content of the structure ( non deleted intervals) :
Iterate over the non deleted new intervals, and collects the associated orignal intervals .

Solution 2 , for fast insertion of new intervals (log(n)), slow deletion (n) : 
A simple way to achieve Log time would be to use two binary trees. One where you use the min of the interval, the other where you use the max. 
Deletion would '2Log(N)'

```
Find all the interval with min < x log(n)
Find all the interval with max > x log(n)
Intersect the two previous set (n)
```